# web resource caching issue

Tags: url, caching, web

I have a website with some css and images.

I pushed some changes about the css and images to live.

I open IE/Firefox and type the URL to my website and hit return.

Then nothing is updated. I saw the IE/FF is not even try to ask for update, so there is no 304 returned.

I have to F5 fresh to get new content, but my users may not do this.

Does anybody know what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is your HTTP server? You'll need to have it set the `Cache-Control: no-cache` HTTP header to disable caching at all your users.

Comment: I still want to cache it but I want it to get update every time I change it.

Comment: Then you need `Cache-control: must-revalidate`